# Boundaries of homotopic simplices and equivalent definitions of homotopies

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplicial-stuff

This question is motivated by my attempt at proving that

> **Proposition:** let $X$ be a simplicial set and $x,y \in X_n$. If $x$ and $y$ are homotopic, then $\partial x = \partial y$.

where $\partial z = (d_0z,\dots,d_nz)$.

The references I am using are May's *Simplicial Objects in Algebraic Topology* and Goerss and Jardine's 
*Simplicial Homotopy Theory*.

In the latter, a homotopy of maps $h : f \simeq g$ is defined as a simplicial map $h : X \times \Delta^1 \to Y$ such that $hi_0 = f$ and $hi_1 =g$ where $i_j$ are the inclusions of $X$ into $X \times \Delta^1$ via

$$X \simeq X \times \Delta^0 \xrightarrow{(1,d^j)} X \times \Delta^1.$$

Two simplices $x,y \in X_n \subset X$ are homotopic if the maps $x,y : \Delta^n \to X$ induced by these are homotopic.

On the other hand May's book says that two simplices $x$ and $y$ are homotopic if $\partial x = \partial y$ and there exists $z \in X_{n+1}$ such that $d_nz =x, d_{n+1}z = y$ and $d_i z = s_{n-1}d_ix = s_{n-1}d_iy$ for each $i$. Similarly, a homotopy between maps $f,g :X \to Y$ is a collection of maps $h_i : X_q \to Y_{q+1}$ for each $0 \leq i \leq q$ that verify a series of combinatorial identities.

How are these two equivalent definitions related? And more concretely, is there a succint proof of the fact that the boundaries of homotopic simplices coincide from the more 'categorical' definition of homotopy?

Comment: If you see a simplex $x\in X_n$ as a map $\Delta^n \to X$ through Yoneda, both definitions should coincide (at least on Kan complexes). I don't have the time to check that now with the definitions you are giving, hence just a comment for now. I'll come back for a complete answer tonight if I find the time :)

Comment: I tried using Yoneda, but I could get anywhere. For example, to prove that $\partial x = \partial y $ I tried to use the fact that $d_ix = x(d_i1_n) = h(d_i1_n,0)$ and $d_iy = y(d_i1_n) = h(d_i1_n,1)$ but I have not managed to relate these two facts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not true, even for Kan complexes. Indeed take a topological space $X$ and its singular simplicial set $Sing(X)$. Then a simplex $x\in Sing(X)$ is a map $x: |\Delta^n| \to X$.

Now suppose you have two simplices $x,y\in Sing(X)$. A homotopy in May's sense between the two is a map $\Delta^n\times \Delta^1\to Sing(X)$ satisfying the appropriate things, and under the $|-|\dashv Sing$ adjunction this translates to a continuous map $|\Delta^n|\times |\Delta^1|\cong |\Delta^n\times \Delta^1|\to X$ satisfying the obvious thing.

But now this is just a topological homotopy between $x,y: |\Delta^n|\to X$, which can of course not respect the boundary of $|\Delta^n|$, in particular we can clearly have $\partial x \neq \partial y$ (take for instance $X=\mathbb R^2$ and a homotopy that crushes the standard $|\Delta^2|\subset \mathbb R^2$ to a point )

I think they defined different notions with different purposes : May defines homotopy rel $\partial \Delta^n$, so as to define homotopy groups later on, whereas Jardine just defines homotopy in a general sense.

In particular you will not be able to prove the equivalence.

What you will be able to prove is something along those lines : if $h:\Delta^n\times \Delta^1\to X$ is a homotopy between $x,y$ whose restriction to $\partial\Delta^n\times \Delta^1$ factors through the projection $\partial \Delta^n\times \Delta^1\to \partial \Delta^n$, then $\partial x = \partial y$ and if $X$ is a Kan complex, then $x,y$ are "May-homotopic".

Moreover, if $x,y$ are "May-homotopic", then they are "Jardine-homotopic" rel $\partial \Delta^n$

Comment: Thanks Max, this makes a lot of sense. I was under the impression that I could prove such thing because May claims so in the definition of homotopy, but I was unaware that homotopic meant homotopic relative to the boundary in that case.